# Acumatica Scan barcode

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica project , on Receipt screen have a lookup button "Add Item".  When Inventory lookup show dialog ( it's FromDetail template ), i will scan barcode from my bill. But, i must scan second times it to working.
How can i to filter grid details and set checked a row filtered according barcode ? And how can to know row count filtered? .  Please help me.

The below figure illustrates.

[snip code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e71i.png)

[Screen Receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ue3g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be in a much better position with **FieldVerifying** handler implemented as follows for the **INSiteStatusFilter.BarCode** field to split scanned barcode and assign the new values both to **BarCode** field (though the `PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs.New` property) and custom unbound **FilterQtySelected** field. Then inside the **FieldUpdated** handler you will select all records from the detail grid, that satisfy filter condition and set **Qty. Selected**  according to your unbound **FilterQtySelected** field:

```
public class INReceiptEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry>
{
    public class INSiteStatusFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<INSiteStatusFilter>
    {
        #region QtySelected
        public abstract class filterQtySelected : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXQuantity]
        public virtual decimal? FilterQtySelected { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

    public void INSiteStatusFilter_BarCode_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        var barCode = (string)e.NewValue;
        string[] codes = barCode.Split(';');
        decimal qtySelected;
        if (codes.Length == 3 && decimal.TryParse(codes[2], out qtySelected))
        {
            e.NewValue = codes[1];
            sender.GetExtension<INSiteStatusFilterExt>(e.Row).FilterQtySelected = qtySelected;
            return;
        }
        sender.GetExtension<INSiteStatusFilterExt>(e.Row).FilterQtySelected = null;
    }

    public void INSiteStatusFilter_BarCode_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        INSiteStatusFilter filter = e.Row as INSiteStatusFilter;
        var filterExt = filter.GetExtension<INSiteStatusFilterExt>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.BarCode) || !filterExt.FilterQtySelected.HasValue) return;

        foreach(INSiteStatusSelected record in Base.sitestatus.Select())
        {
            record.Selected = true;
            record.QtySelected = sender.GetExtension<INSiteStatusFilterExt>(e.Row).FilterQtySelected;
            Base.sitestatus.Update(record);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a barcode pattern  P01X377;421364-N;10 . I want to when scanner    i split it and set Qtyselected = 10 , barcode field =  421364-N. How can do it ?

Comment: Thank you for supported. it's working , i using method Setvalue<field>(obj,obj) of cache for update barcode field before split string input from scannr

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add your custom 2D format support on the existing barcode infrastructure screens via a customization project.